# Не работает код в HTML

Tags: javascript, математика, случайные-числа

Уже все проверил. Нашел похожий код и переписал заново, но все равно не запускается. Писал его как в отдельном файле так и в HTML  через  добавлял. Пока только вникаю в JS, может надо еще как-то подгружать? Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Spin</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <button id="spin">Spin</button>
    <span class="arrow"></span>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="one">1</div>
        <div class="two">2</div>
        <div class="three">3</div>
        <div class="four">4</div>
        <div class="five">5</div>
        <div class="six">6</div>
        <div class="seven">7</div>
        <div class="eight">8</div>
    </div>

<script>
    let container = document.querySelector('.container');
let btn = document.getElementById('spin');
let number = Math.ceil(Math.random()*1000);

btn.onclick = function(){
    container.style.transform = "rotate(" + number + " deg)";
    number += Math.ceil(Math.random()*1000);
}
</script>

   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Покажите HTML, к которому это применяется. Возможно не так подключили файл JS или он выполняется до загрузки DOM

Comment: [Вот так это работает](https://codepen.io/SwaD1984/pen/zYapRwN). В style надо было указать больше вариантов для разных браузеров

Comment: @SwaD Спасибо, щас буду разбираться